# Generic swift IOS "is not a subtype of" code compilation error

Tags: xcode, swift, generics

I am learning generics in swift. And don't understand what is going wrong.

Anybody, please explain how can I insert generic template in another template.

Declaration of `BasePresenter` class looks like

```
class BasePresenter<VIEW : BaseView>{
```

Code with error below at the picture:

[image: *UPD*]

Comment: Why have you declared presenter as an array? Any reasons? Looks like you just wanted  var presenter:PRESENTER ?

Comment: @Shripada, thanks for response. Yes, it is my mistake. Made it as single object. But it does not resolve problem

Comment: can you update your question with correct screenshot? The screenshot still depicts the wrong code

Comment: @Shripada, I've updated screenshot, but I mentioned above the error is same

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? We are facing exactly the same issue with our own MVP library.

Answer (score 0):

In your class declaration, the type that you seem to introduce, i.e, PRESENTER, is unwanted. I am not sure, why compiler is allowing this partial type declaration though and later correctly gives an error when you try to create variable using such partial type. The workaround for now is to avoid this type and directly declare your presenter variable to be of type BasePresenter, or represent your PRESENTER type using a type alias:

Something like-

```
class BaseViewController <VIEW: BaseView> : UIViewController, BaseView{

typealias PRESENTER  = BasePresenter<VIEW>!
var presenter : PRESENTER!

//Rest of the class body...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But inheritor of `BaseViewController` should have instance of inheritor of  `BasePresenter` in variable `var presenter`.  How I can do it?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You can assign to the presenter, any sub type of the BasePresenter.

Comment: @Shripada So we can use that var as the specific `PRESENTER` implementation and call its methods directly without casting the `BasePresenter` to to the `PRESENTER` in a subclass of `BaseViewController`.